# Grep in couple thousands files

Tags: files, grep, performance

I have directory with cca 26 000 files and I need to grep in all these files. Problem is, that I need it as fast as possible, so it's not ideal to make script where grep will take name of one file from find command and write matches to file. Before "arguments list too long" issue it took cca 2 minutes to grep in all this files.
Any ideas how to do it?
edit: there is a script that is making new files all the time, so it's not possible to put all files to different dirs.

Comment: use `find` with `xargs` or `grep -R`

Comment: It works good, but it takes 10 minutes...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With `find`:

```
cd /the/dir
find . -type f -exec grep pattern {} +
```

(`-type f` is to only search in *regular* files (also excluding symlinks even if they point to regular files). If you want to search in any type of file except directories (but beware there are some types of files like fifos or /dev/zero that you generally don't want to read), replace `-type f` with the GNU-specific `! -xtype d` (`-xtype d` matches for files of type *directory* after symlink resolution)).

With GNU `grep`:

```
grep -r pattern /the/dir
```

(but beware that unless you have a recent version of GNU grep, that will follow symlinks when descending into directories). Non-regular files won't be searched unless you add a `-D read` option. Recent versions of GNU `grep` will still not search inside symlinks though.

Very old versions of GNU `find` did not  support the standard `{} +` syntax, but there you could use the non-standard:

```
cd /the/dir &&
  find . -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 grep pattern
```

Performances are likely to be I/O bound. That is the time to do the search would be the time needed to read all that data from storage.

If the data is on a redundant disk array, reading several files at a time might improve performance (and could degrade them otherwise). If the performances are not I/O bound (because for instance all the data is in cache), and you have multiple CPUs, concurrent `greps` might help as well. You can do that with GNU `xargs`'s `-P` option.

For instance, if the data is on a RAID1 array with 3 drives, or if the data is in cache and you have 3 CPUs whose time to spare:

```
cd /the/dir &&
  find . -type f -print0 | xargs -n1000 -r0P3 grep pattern
```

(here using `-n1000` to spawn a new `grep` every 1000 files, up to 3 running in parallel at a time).

However note that if the output of `grep` is redirected, you'll end up with badly interleaved output from the 3 `grep` processes, in which case you may want to run it as:

```
find . -type f -print0 | stdbuf -oL xargs -n1000 -r0P3 grep pattern
```

(on a recent GNU or FreeBSD system) or use the `--line-buffered` option of GNU `grep`.

If `pattern` is a fixed string, adding the `-F` option could improve matters.

If it's not multi-byte character data, or if for the matching of that pattern, it doesn't matter whether the data is multi-byte character or not, then:

```
cd /the/dir &&
  LC_ALL=C grep -r pattern .
```

could improve performance significantly.

If you end up doing such searches often, then you may want to index your data using one of the many search engines out there.

Answer (score 2):

26000 files in a single directory is a lot for most filesystems. It's likely that a significant part of the time is taken reading this big directory. Consider splitting it into smaller directories with only a few hundred files each.

Calling `find` cannot explain poor performance unless you do it wrong. It's a fast way of traversing a directory, and of ensuring that you don't risk attempting to execute a command line that's too long. Make sure that you use `-exec grep PATTERN {} +`, which packs as many files as it can per command invocation, and not `-exec grep PATTERN {} \;`, which executes `grep` once per file: executing the command once per file is likely to be significantly slower.

Comment: Thanks, I will google something about it and probably I will split that.
I made exactly what you are writing about and it took 3 times longer than only grep...

Comment: Gilles, are you saying that performance would differ significantly for 26,000 files in one directory versus 26,000 files distributed over, say, 100 directories?

Comment: @user001 Yes. How much they differ depends on the filesystem and possibly on the underlying storage, but I'd expect any filesystem to be measurably faster with 260 files in each of 100 directories compared with 26000 files in a single directory.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I asked a follow-up [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/466883/14960) on this point in order to understand the basis for the discrepancy.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to grep ALL the files multiple times (as you said, running a script) I would suggest looking into ram disks, copy all files there and then grep the files the multiple times, this will speed up your search by a factor of at least 100x.

You just need enough ram.
Else, you should look into indexing the files, eg. into lucene or a nosql database and then running queries upon that.

Comment: As noted elsewhere, this doesn't help the fact that there are too many files to run a `grep` against. There's also the point that: "there is a script that is making new files all the time, so it's not possible to put all files to different dirs."

Answer (score 0):

If you are open/able to rely on an external utility, the popular utility [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) provides the binary `rg` which uses parallelism and smart file filtering by default.

You can control the level of parallelism if you wish:

> -j, --threads NUM
>
> The approximate number of threads to use. A value of 0 (which is the default) causes ripgrep to choose the thread count using heuristics.

Additionally, quoting the ripgrep README, `rg` "is built on top of Rust's regex engine [which] uses finite automata, SIMD, and aggressive literal optimizations to make searching very fast."

Beside this, there are other aspects that make `rg` faster than `grep`. Depending on your situation, you might want to turn some of these off:

- By default `rg` is recursive.

If your directory contains subdirectories that you do not want to search, you can disable the recursive behaviour with `--max-depth 1`.

- By default `rg` does not search files present in any .gitignore or similar file, nor does it search hidden files, and binary files.

If you want to remove those filters you can add the -u flag (once (`-u`) for ignored files, twice (`-uu`) for ignored and hidden files, three times (`-uuu`) to stop all filters).

Assuming that you have subdirectories in your directory that you do not want to search and that the default filtering is useful in your situation, you would then run (from your directory):

```bsh
rg --max-depth 1 pattern
```

Outside your directory, you'd have to add its path:

```bsh
rg --max-depth 1 pattern /path/to/dir
```

If you want to search ignored files and hidden files, but not binary files, you'd use:

```bsh
rg --max-depth 1 -uu pattern
```

If you want to follow symlinks, you have to add the `-L` flag.

Answer (score -2):

All files in the directory

```
grep 'search string' *
```

with recursively

```
grep -R 'search string' *
```

Comment: Care to elaborate the -1?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but there are a few issues with yours: the OP mentionned a "arg list too long", which your first one won't fix and is probably what the OP was doing before. The second one doesn't help either in that regard (would have helped had you used `.` instead of `*`). `*` will exclude dot files (though with -R, not the ones in the recursed directories). -R as opposed to -r follows symlinks even with recent versions of GNU grep. You'll also have an issue with files in the current directory whose name starts with `-`