# GNU parallel excessively slow

Tags: grep, xargs, gnu-parallel

I need to run `grep` on a couple of million files. Therefore I tried to speed it up, following the [two approaches mentioned here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197353/19529): `xargs -P -n` and [`GNU parallel`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/%20GNU%20parallel). I tried this on a subset of my files (9026 in number), and this was the result:

1. With `xargs -P 8 -n 1000`, very fast:

   ```
   $ time find tex -maxdepth 1 -name "*.json" | \
                   xargs -P 8 -n 1000 grep -ohP "'pattern'" > /dev/null

   real    0m0.085s
   user    0m0.333s
   sys     0m0.058s
   ```
2. With `parallel`, very slow:

   ```
   $ time find tex -maxdepth 1 -name "*.json" | \
                   parallel -j 8 grep -ohP "'pattern'" > /dev/null

   real    0m21.566s
   user    0m22.021s
   sys     0m18.505s
   ```
3. Even sequential `xargs` is faster than `parallel`:

   ```
   $ time find tex -maxdepth 1 -name "*.json" | \
                   xargs grep -ohP 'pattern' > /dev/null

   real    0m0.242s
   user    0m0.209s
   sys     0m0.040s
   ```

`xargs -P n` does not work for me because the output from all the processes gets interleaved, which does not happen with `parallel`. So I would like to use `parallel` without incurring this huge slowdown.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

1. Following the [answer by Ole Tange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/273315/19529), I tried `parallel -X`, the results  are here, for completeness:

   ```
   $ time find tex -maxdepth 1 -name "*.json" | \
       parallel -X -j 8 grep -ohP "'pattern'" > /dev/null

   real    0m0.563s
   user    0m0.583s
   sys     0m0.110s
   ```
2. **Fastest solution:** Following the [comment by @cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273170/gnu-parallel-excessively-slow#comment474427_273170), I tried to grep with `-H` option (to force printing the filenames), and sorting. Results here:

   ```
   time find tex -maxdepth 1 -name '*.json' -print0 | \
       xargs -0r -P 9 -n 500 grep --line-buffered -oHP 'pattern' | \
       sort -t: -k1 | cut -d: -f2- > /dev/null

   real    0m0.144s
   user    0m0.417s
   sys     0m0.095s
   ```

Comment: I think the slowdown might be caused by `parallel` launching new shell for each invocation. If yes, is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: how many lines of output do you expect?

Comment: @1_CR I expect 2 - 10 lines of output from each file.

Comment: Ole Tange is usually on this forum and will probably have the last word on this but I suspect buffering up those many lines to be able to finally report them in order might have something to do with it

Comment: Have you tried `xargs -P8` with `-H` (`--with-filename`) instead of `-h` (`--no-filename`) option to `grep`, then pipe through `sort -t: -k1 | cut -d: -f2-`  to sort by filename and then strip the filename?

Comment: @cas, you're going to need `-s` to enable stable sort (disable last resort comparison) else output from within a file could come out of order

Comment: also, i would suggest using `find ... -print0` and `xargs -0` so that your script works even with filenames containing annoying characters like spaces and newlines.   `time find tex -maxdepth 1 -name '*.json' -print0 | xargs -0r -P 8 -n 1000 grep -oHP 'pattern' | sort -t: -k1 | cut -d: -f2- > /dev/null`

Comment: not sure what you mean by the `-s` option (how does it differ from `sort -k1,1`?).  BTW, i seem to have found a bug in GNU `grep` where `-H -z` doesn't act like `-l -z`  even though the description for `-z` implies it should.

Comment: @cas, I meant the one from [here] (https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html). Apologies for brevity, on a mobile device now

Comment: ah, okay.  the info docs mention what `--stable` does, but the man page only lists `--stable` with minimal description.  I hate the way GNU tools leave important info out of man pages and expect you to rely on their crappy .info format.

Comment: actually, not a bug in `grep`. my mistake, should be using `-Z`, not `-z`.  but using that reveals that `sort` can't use NUL as a field delimiter (as opposed to line separator) anyway, so there's no point in using `-print0` in `find` or `-0` in xargs.

Comment: @cas : Thanks for the `grep -H` suggestion. However, I still get mangled output, this time **within the same line**: like so: `line1word1_line2word1_line1word2`.

Comment: This got solved by using `grep --line-buffered`

Comment: By using `xargs -P` you still risk getting mangled output - even with `grep --line-buffered`. See an example of mangling on https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_alternatives.html#DIFFERENCES-BETWEEN-xargs-AND-GNU-Parallel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `parallel -X`. As written in the comments the overhead of starting a new shell and opening files for buffering for each argument is probably the cause.

Be aware that GNU Parallel will never be as fast as xargs because of that. Expect an overhead of 10 ms per job. With -X this overhead is less significant as you process more arguments in one job.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This indeed came out to be about twice as fast as xargs. I have included the results in the question.