# Bash scripting in a Maildir directory

Tags: files, grep, maildir

I want to grep across 500 files in a Maildir directory. I issued the command

```
grep MyPattern *
```

I got the error message:

```
bash: /usr/bin/grep: Argument list too long
```

So I stored the list of files in a file MyFiles, and issued the following

```
for i in $(`cat MyFiles`); do echo $i; done
```

Before I did a grep, I wanted to do an echo just as a check. But this gave the following error

```
bash: 1434361691.M617282P6399V0000000000000808I00000000000E16C1_23.ananda-linux,S=10055:2,S: command not found
```

where that 1434... thing is the first file in the directory.

So back to the original question. How do I grep across all these files in the mailbox. And I have larger mailboxes containing 50000 or more emails.

Comment: There's nothing inherent in a Maildir that makes this special or any different from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85789/ .

Answer (score 1):

Ask `grep` itself to construct the file list, by recursing from the current directory:

```
grep -r MyPattern .
```

This isn’t quite the same as `*`, since it will search in sub-directories, but for mail directories that’s usually what you want.

Answer (score 1):

When the shell executes an external command, the length of the command line, after expansion of any filename globbing pattern such as `*`, must not exceed a particular length.

In your case, `grep 'PATTERN' *` expands to a too long command for the shell to execute.

In your second example:

```
for i in $(`cat MyFiles`); do echo $i; done
```

you try to iterate over the filenames stored in `MyFiles`, but you are getting the syntax very wrong.

```
$(`cat MyFiles`)
```

is the same as

```
$( $(cat MyFiles) )
```

which means the contents of the `MyFiles` is going to be interpreted as a command.  This is why you get the `command not found` error.

There are several ways to remedy this, but looping over the contents of your file is not really a good one.

Stephen gives a good solution [in his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/440149/116858), and another one would be, assuming that your current working directory is your Maildir folder,

```
find . -type f -exec grep 'PATTERN' {} +
```

This would execute `grep` a few times on as large batches of files *as possible*.

This is similar to

```
printf '%s\n' * | xargs grep 'PATTERN'
```

but the `find` command handles filenames with spaces and embedded newlines.

The `printf` command here will output one filename per line.  It does not suffer from the same problem as `grep 'PATTERN' *` since it's very likely a *built-in* command, and therefore does not have to be executed as an external command by the shell.

Your loop solution would also work, but rather than looping over the output of `cat`, you could simply do

```
for name in *; do
    grep 'PATTERN' "$name"
done
```

This assumes that there are *only regular files* in the current directory.

To make sure that you only process mail messages, you may use

```
for name in *,*; do
    grep 'PATTERN' "$name" /dev/null
done
```

This iterates over names that contains at least one comma. I have also added `/dev/null` to force `grep` to output the name of the files matching the given pattern.  You can remove `/dev/null` and instead use `-H` with `grep` if your `grep` supports this.

Looping like this is slow, since we execute `grep` once for each single file in the directory.