# grep a pattern across huge fileset without GNU parallel

Tags: linux, files, grep, performance

I want to grep a pattern across 10M files really fast in a 36 core machine i tried this

```
find . -name '*.xml' -type f | xargs  -P 20 grep "username" >> output
```

But i am getting some other results in between.

Is there any better way to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the "other" results and what are you looking for? The line content? The filename? What is your expected output?

Comment: You're working on XML files? What is it that you are trying to extract from these? Can you give examples of actual data? XML documents are best parsed using XML parsers and queried using e.g. XPath queries, not by line-oriented tools like `grep`.

Comment: @bu5hman i mean result not matching with my pattern

Comment: CPU is likely not the bottleneck if you're grepping for fixed strings. So parallelising is more likely to harm than help. See also [Grep in couple thousands files](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/85789) and [Recursive grep vs find / -type f -exec grep {} \; Which is more efficient/faster?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/131576)

Comment: How are files stored? Redundant RAID arrays? HDDs or SSDs? Can you arrange for the output to be stored on different HDDs?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas HDDs only

Comment: @user3398900 So using 20 separate processes that all read off the one disk would possibly saturate the disk I/O. It's disk-bound rather than CPU bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your data is on non-RAIDed HDDs, I doubt you'll get better performance from parallelizing, the bottle neck is most likely to be I/O, not CPU.

```
LC_ALL=C grep -rwF --include='*.xml' username . > /on/some/other/disk/output
```

May be close to the best you can achieve.

To parallelize, you'd want to do it as:

```
LC_ALL=C find . -name '*.xml' -type f -print0 |
  LC_ALL=C xargs -r0P20 -n 1000 grep -HFw --line-buffered username > output
```

assuming there's no output line (input line + file pathname) longer than 4KiB, and note the lines of all 20 concurrent greps will end up interleaved.

See:

- [Grep in couple thousands files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85789)
- [Recursive grep vs find / -type f -exec grep {} \; Which is more efficient/faster?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131535)

for details.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the pattern being too general. Usually the command line utilities print errors to the stderr or the terminal. They shouldn't get in the output file.

Comment: Ok updated the one i have tried is there any better way to do it ???

Answer (score 0):

If you are `grep`ping `xml` files in this way then your search will return the entire line containing the search string and, if the `xml` file has no newlines, the entire file contents. Quite a lot of "other" across 10M files.

As per @Kusalananda comment it isn't good practice to brute force an `xml` with `grep` and an `xml` parser e.g. `xmllint` is a better tool, however, if you insist ......

Check `man` for `grep` and read up on the `-o` option to restrict the returned value and use `regex` that defines the whole length of the match you are looking to find.

If `username` is an attribute

```
grep -o 'username="[^"]*"'
```

Or better

```
xmllint --xpath "//@username"
```

If `username` is a node then something like

```
grep -o "username>[^<][^<]*"
```

Or better

```
xmllint --xpath "//username"
```

With either of the `xmllint` queries, just wrap the query in `string()` to extract the attribute or node text.

```
xmllint --xpath "string(//username)"
xmllint --xpath "string(//@username)"
```